# The project was not built due to "Could not delete '/Help/build/classes/exportFile'.".

Tags: java, eclipse

When I imported my project in Eclipse Oxygen, it gave the below error.
"The project was not built due to "Could not delete '/Help/build/classes/exportFile'.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent"

Googled and got that to delete the contents of the bin folder and clean the project. But there's no bin folder. Tried cleaning, still the same error. What else can be done

Comment: deleted the contents inside /Help/build/ and it worked

Comment: Please post that as a self-answer if it has resolved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You found a solution yourself, but here are some more informations about this error.

First, you said, your search brought up answers where deleting the `bin`-directory manually solves this but you don't have this directory. Reason for that is that you configured your project to write classes to the `classes`-directory (`bin` is the default).

The "cannot delete" message appears mainly on Windows systems if there is another process keeping a lock on the directory or files within. The classic reason for that is that you currently run the application or that you have an Explorer window open that shows the content of this directory. Closing the application/Explorer window normally solves the problem. Sometimes the lock keeps staying. A way to find the culprit is using Sysinternal's ProcessExplorer. It allows you to search for it by using `Find`->`Find handle or DLL`. The result can be clicked on and you can even forcefully close that entry, releasing the lock (some programs don't like that but I never had any problems doing that).

But sometimes it's actually necessary to reboot the system if you can't get rid off the lock otherwise.